# Is it possible to construct a `persistent` schema in pieces?

Tags: haskell, persistent

Say I have 4 modules: Common, A, B, and Main, and I want the following schema:

```hs
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Common
  commonField Int
A
  commonId CommonId
  aField Int
B
  commonId CommonId
  bField Int
|]
```

But I want to split it across the Common, A, and B modules. I then want Main to depend on all of them and to contain the database logic.

I tried the following (ignoring B)

```hs
-- module Common
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateCommon"] [persistLowerCase|
Common
  commonField Int
|]

-- module A
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateA"] [persistLowerCase|
A
  commonId CommonId
  aField Int
|]
```

but the resulting migration removes the foreign constraint from A to Common.

I tried storing and concatenating the results of the `persistLowerCase` quasiquoter before calling share, but that led to a type error about CommonId not being in scope.

The only other solution I can think of is storing strings, concatenating them, and calling the quasiquoter on that, and that doesn't seem good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062707/foreign-key-constraints-in-yesod-persistent ? as far as I know there should be no restrictions, as long as you export all types from `Common` module